# Automatic stack

Tags: formal-languages, stacks

Each context-free language has an automatic stack received by a non-deterministic blank.
That is, it will not uphold the following determinism requirement:

[image]

Comment: How can I prove or disprove this claim?

Comment: Maybe Anat would help you out or yoav..
Try asking them! Or just delete this post before someone else sees it.